# QuaggaJS and Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking at a barcode scanner called QuaggaJS.

But looking at the examples, I'm not sure how to adapt it to Angular. For example, the demo they use at http://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/examples/file_input.js is full of jQuery.

What is the best way to integrate this with Angular? Should I keep the jQuery, should I create a new directive, etc?

Any ideas would be warmly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for anyone else trying to do this; here's what I did.

It's a partial extract but you should get the idea. `App` contains the config, the Quagga callbacks are as they are in all the other examples you see (sans the jQuery).

Then in Angular I made a directive so that the file/photo of the barcode can get saved directly as a pointer in some JSON variable: `<input type="file" my-file="myItem.photo" my-file-type="barcode" />`

```
var App = {
    ...
};

App.init();

Quagga.onProcessed(function(result) {
    ...
};

Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {
    ...
}

angular.module( ...
        // Read files into angular
            .directive('file', [function () {
                return {
                    scope: {
                        myFile: '=',
                        myFileType: '@'
                    },

                    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                        element.bind('change', function (changeEvent) {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.myFile = changeEvent.target.files[0];

                                if (scope.myFileType != null && scope.myFileType !== undefined && scope.myFileType == "barcode") {
                                    App.decode(URL.createObjectURL(scope.myFile));
                                }
                            });
                        });
                }
            }
        }])
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can coexist with another framework easily enough. Take whichever example page you're building from, find and replace all of the `$` calls with `jQuery`, and put jQuery into [no-conflict mode](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/):

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<!-- rest of source follows -->
```

This will get you up a live page to edit against, and then you can Angular-ize the sample as you have the chance to. It'll be a lot easier to see exactly *how* you can go about this once you're looking at a page with both frameworks available to you.

You might well find you want to work some or all of this into a `<quagga-scanner>` [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) once you've do this, especially if you'll use the functionality on many pages, but the best way to make this decision is almost certainly to try.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be a little vague, and I am sorry for that, but that's the best I can judge from the current scenario.

You can always mix-and-match, but it's not really advisable. Creating a directive would be a futile attempt, but rather a component should do.

As with the answer by Will, you can always use jQuery's no-conflict mode, then use Angular with it.

Just a note about performance, jQuery is a really big library; big in the sense that it's really resource-heavy, and you don't need half of the stuff.

You can try to use Angular's built-in jQuery [`jqLite`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which is a stripped down version of jQuery and contains only the things Angular doesn't do (as a DOM manipulation library).